# django admin site view one to one classes fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

in my models:

```
class Professor(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  salary = models.FloatField()
class Student(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  birth_date = models.DateField()
```

in my admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

UserAdmin.list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','is_active','date_joined', 'is_staff')
```

how can i display inside Users admin site if user is professor or student?is it possible to get access to properties like salary which are individual based on the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom methods in list_display. This is the code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','is_active','date_joined', 'is_staff', 'user_type', 'salary')

    def user_type(self, instance):
        try:
            instance.student
            return "student"
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            return "professor"

    def salary(self, instance):
        try:
            return instance.professor.salary
        except Professor.DoesNotExist:
            return "N/A"

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        # To reduce database calls
        return qs.select_related('student', 'professor')


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

It will add additional columns `user_type` and `salary` to change_list admin page.

**UPDATED**:
Thanks to [@Adrián López](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959899/adrian-lopez). Now subclassing from django builtin UserAdmin.

Comment: This is missing the obligatory `model` attribute.
Also it would allow editing the password hash, that would be quite a mess. Make `UserAdmin` extend django's bultin `UserAdmin` instead, There's quite a bit of functionality that you'd be missing if you use a plain model admin for the `User` model.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ProfessorInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Professor

class StudentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Student

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ProfessorInline, StudentInline]


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

It's not perfect. It should show in your `User` admin panel both `Professor` and `Student` fields. It won't explicitly state if is a `Professor` or an `Student`. That doesn't make much sense to be honest, you aren't using herency so it is technically possible that you'd have an `User` who is both a `Professsor` and an `Student` at the same time.

You can try `TabularInline` as well, if you like it better.